# How can I tell when all images on a page are loaded using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I’m using jQuery for my project. `$(function(){...})` fires the function “when the DOM is ready” — this doesn’t say that all images are loaded, right?

Is there an event that gets fired when every image is loaded too?

Comment: if you mean specific image, use its own onload event.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you mean

http://api.jquery.com/ready/

versus

http://api.jquery.com/load-event/

*Example: Run a function when the page is fully loaded including graphics.*

```
$(window).load(function () {
  // run code
});
```

without jQuery:

```
window.onload=function() {
  alert(document.images.length);
}
```

Comment: is it actually allowed to use this function twice on a page? like having it once in my headed.php and once in an external script.js file which is loaded in header.php as well. so I'm actually declaring the function twice? is that okay?

Comment: Actually one would override the other. You can ask in JS - if (!window.onload) window.onload=... but how the same in jQuery looks I would need to look up.

Comment: It seems to be a case when this doesn't work: browser - Google Chrome, case - page cached, browser restarted. My application performs some ajax requests on DOMContentLoaded - and when it comes to watching onload event - it never fires. There's another way to do it - check if all images has width property set ($('img').width()), it works with all browsers except Google Chrome. I think I've found a bug in GC :)

Answer (score 3):

You can check on load event of image tag. This will get fired when image loading completes.

```
$("img").load(function(){
   // your code
});
```

Comment: won't this fire for each and every image?

Answer (score 0):

window.onload will solve this, I wrote about this there: http://amrelgarhy.com/blog/how-to-tell-when-images-have-loaded/